# javascript timer strange behavior

Tags: javascript, asp.net, timer

I'm working on an ASP.NET web project, I've used a Javascript timer to perform periodical operations (I change page content in this timer), but I think this timer is not functioning properly, for instance when I set its interval to 10000 (10sec), it tick on 10 second intervals, but also I have a tick just 1 second after the last tick, its tick pattern is something like this:

tick-1s-tic------10 s-----tick-1s tick------10s tick-1s-tick-----10s tick......

when I set my interval to 1 second, I fill there is an extra tick after 100 ms, what is going wrong here? what is this extra tick?

here is my JS code:

```
pageload:
                ChangeNewsTimer();
```

...

```
            function ChangeNewsTimer() {
            var timer = setTimeout("ChangeNewsTimer()", 5000);
            var g = document.getElementById('<%=HFLux.ClientID %>').value.split(',');
            imgLuxIndex++;
            if (imgLuxIndex == g.length)
                imgLuxIndex = 0;

            document.getElementById('<%=hpLux1.ClientID %>').style.color = 'white';
            document.getElementById('<%=hpLux2.ClientID %>').style.color = 'white';
            document.getElementById('<%=hpLux3.ClientID %>').style.color = 'white';
            document.getElementById('<%=hpLux4.ClientID %>').style.color = 'white';
            document.getElementById('<%=hpLux5.ClientID %>').style.color = 'white';
            document.getElementById('<%=hpLux6.ClientID %>').style.color = 'white';
            document.getElementById('<%=hpLux7.ClientID %>').style.color = 'white';
            document.getElementById('<%=hpLux8.ClientID %>').style.color = 'white';

            if (imgLuxIndex == 0)
                document.getElementById('<%=hpLux1.ClientID %>').style.color = 'yellow';
            else if (imgLuxIndex == 1)
                document.getElementById('<%=hpLux2.ClientID %>').style.color = 'yellow';
            else if (imgLuxIndex == 2)
                document.getElementById('<%=hpLux3.ClientID %>').style.color = 'yellow';
            else if (imgLuxIndex == 3)
                document.getElementById('<%=hpLux4.ClientID %>').style.color = 'yellow';
            else if (imgLuxIndex == 4)
                document.getElementById('<%=hpLux5.ClientID %>').style.color = 'yellow';
            else if (imgLuxIndex == 5)
                document.getElementById('<%=hpLux6.ClientID %>').style.color = 'yellow';
            else if (imgLuxIndex == 6)
                document.getElementById('<%=hpLux7.ClientID %>').style.color = 'yellow';
            else if (imgLuxIndex == 7)
                document.getElementById('<%=hpLux8.ClientID %>').style.color = 'yellow';

            var gg = g[imgLuxIndex].split(';');
            document.getElementById('<%=imgLux.ClientID %>').src = gg[0];
            document.getElementById('<%=lblLuxResName.ClientID %>').value = document.getElementById('<%=lblLuxResName.ClientID %>').innerHTML = gg[1];
```

/////////////////////////////////

```
            var d = document.getElementById('<%=HFUserCooking.ClientID %>').value.split(',');
            usercookingINdex++;
            //alert(d.length);
            if (usercookingINdex == d.length)
                usercookingINdex = 0;

            var dd = d[usercookingINdex].split(';');
            //alert(usercookingINdex);
            document.getElementById('<%=imgUserCooking.ClientID %>').src = dd[0];
            document.getElementById('<%=lblImageSender.ClientID %>').value = document.getElementById('<%=lblImageSender.ClientID %>').innerHTML = dd[1];

            ///////////////


            var w = document.getElementById('<%=HFSlide.ClientID %>').value.split(',');
            imgMainIndex++;
            if (imgMainIndex == 3)
                imgMainIndex = 0;

            document.getElementById('<%=imgMain.ClientID %>').src = w[imgMainIndex];

            var q = document.getElementById('<%=hfHealthNews.ClientID %>').value.split('%');
            newsIndex++;
            var q2 = q[newsIndex].split('$');
            if (newsIndex == 10)
                newsIndex = 0;
            document.getElementById('<%=hpNewsHealthTitle.ClientID %>').value = document.getElementById('<%=hpNewsHealthTitle.ClientID %>').innerHTML = q2[0];
            document.getElementById('<%=lblNewsHealthSummary.ClientID %>').value = document.getElementById('<%=lblNewsHealthSummary.ClientID %>').innerHTML = q2[1];
            document.getElementById('<%=imgNewsHealth.ClientID %>').src = q2[2];
            var yourElement = document.getElementById('<%=hpNewsHealthTitle.ClientID %>');
            yourElement.setAttribute('href', q2[3]);

            var yourElement2 = document.getElementById('<%=hpNewsHealth.ClientID %>');
            yourElement2.setAttribute('href', q2[3]);

            //cooking
            q = document.getElementById('<%=HFCookingNews.ClientID %>').value.split('%');
            newsIndex2++;
            q2 = q[newsIndex2].split('$');
            if (newsIndex2 == 10)
                newsIndex2 = 0;
            document.getElementById('<%=hpCookingNewsTitle.ClientID %>').value = document.getElementById('<%=hpCookingNewsTitle.ClientID %>').innerHTML = q2[0];
            document.getElementById('<%=lblCookingNewsSummary.ClientID %>').value = document.getElementById('<%=lblCookingNewsSummary.ClientID %>').innerHTML = q2[1];
            document.getElementById('<%=imgCookingNews.ClientID %>').src = q2[2];
            var yourElement = document.getElementById('<%=hpNewsHealthTitle.ClientID %>');
            yourElement.setAttribute('href', q2[3]);

            var yourElement2 = document.getElementById('<%=hpCookingNews.ClientID %>');
            yourElement2.setAttribute('href', q2[3]);

            //comment 1
            q = document.getElementById('<%=HFComment1.ClientID %>').value.split('%');
            commentIndex++;
            q2 = q[commentIndex].split('$');
            if (commentIndex == 10)
                commentIndex = 0;

            document.getElementById('<%=hpNewsComment.ClientID %>').value = document.getElementById('<%=hpNewsComment.ClientID %>').innerHTML = q2[0];
            document.getElementById('<%=lblNewsComment.ClientID %>').value = document.getElementById('<%=lblNewsComment.ClientID %>').innerHTML = q2[2];
            var yourElement5 = document.getElementById('<%=hpNewsComment.ClientID %>');
            yourElement5.setAttribute('href', q2[1]);

            //comment 2
            q = document.getElementById('<%=HFComment2.ClientID %>').value.split('%');
            commentIndex2++;

            if (commentIndex2 == q.length - 1)
                commentIndex2 = 0;
            if (q[commentIndex2] != '') {
                q2 = q[commentIndex2].split('$');
                document.getElementById('<%=hpRevComment.ClientID %>').value = document.getElementById('<%=hpRevComment.ClientID %>').innerHTML = q2[0];
                document.getElementById('<%=lblRevComment.ClientID %>').value = document.getElementById('<%=lblRevComment.ClientID %>').innerHTML = q2[2];
            }
            //var yourElement6 = document.getElementById('<%=hpRevComment.ClientID %>');
            //yourElement6.setAttribute('href', q2[1]);

            //comment 3
            q = document.getElementById('<%=HFComment3.ClientID %>').value.split('%');
            commentIndex3++;
            q2 = q[commentIndex3].split('$');
            if (commentIndex3 == 10)
                commentIndex3 = 0;

            document.getElementById('<%=hpResComment.ClientID %>').value = document.getElementById('<%=hpResComment.ClientID %>').innerHTML = q2[0];
            document.getElementById('<%=lblResComment.ClientID %>').value = document.getElementById('<%=lblResComment.ClientID %>').innerHTML = q2[2];
            var yourElement7 = document.getElementById('<%=hpResComment.ClientID %>');
            yourElement7.setAttribute('href', q2[1]);
        }
```

Comment: Please post more of your code - or try to replicate this from scratch.  I don't think what you're seeing can be explained by the limited code that you provided here.  Something like a jsFiddle would be quite helpful here...

Comment: Are you positive that that's the only call to `ChangeNewsTimer()`? I have a feeling there is an unintentional call to `ChangeNewTimer()` in your code somewhere. Also it should be noted that timers in Js often do not execute exactly on their timed code due to Javascript being a single-thread language. I.e. `setTimeout(function() {...}, 0)` will not execute immediately, but after the current code block finishes.

Comment: I've added full code of ChangeNewsTimer, I'm sure this function is not called anywhere else, what you mean after current code block? it is not important when is it executed, but I want it to run only on specific periods of time, currently my function runs in some extra ticks also, so that page update process is not performed smoothly

Answer (score 1):

More than likely you are accidentally calling ChangeNewsTimer more than once onload. Look through your code to make sure you aren't double initializing it. The other option would be to make it so ChangeNewsTimer cannot initialize more than once. Something like this:

```
var ChangeNewsTimerInitialized = false;
function ChangeNewsTimer() {
    if (ChangeNewsTimerInitialized === true) return;
    ChangeNewsTimerInitialized = true;
    var func = function() {
        setTimeout(func, 10000);
        document.getElementById("findme").innerHTML += "<br />tick";
    }
    func();
}
```

Comment: so you mean I call my main function inside my timer function? what are my other options? does JQuery have any timer?

Comment: You are basically using ChangeNewsTimer as an initializer, so I wrote in a catch to only initialize once. You would then move all your code that is currently inside of ChangeNewsTimer instead of the inner function (the func function in my example)